# Maven - exclude a dependency in current module

Tags: maven, dependencies

My Maven project has dependencies A, B, C in it's **dependencies** section, and it also has the dependency D in certain **profile**

I want to invert this, so the project will have the dependencies A,B,C,D in it's **dependencies**, and the profile, which **excludes** the dependency D from the list of dependencies of the project.

I know that I can exclude the **transitive** dependencies, but how to exclude the first-class dependency from a pom.xml?

Comment: Have you looked at optional dependencies in Maven? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: Well, I need to enable (by default) or disable (in production) some dependency, which provides certain code, used only in "development" environment. For the moment, I am using the "profile" which explicitly adds the dependency, so the developers could run the aplication in IDEA (having some environment variables set). Now. from time to time IDEA drops the "profile" from the runtime configuration, which causes lots of questions like "why there's a ClassNotFoundException", so people have to go the "maven -> profiles" dialog in IDEA, and explicitly check the appropriate profile there.

Comment: Isn't exactly that case covered by optional dependencies? You specify all of the dependencies necessary to build the product, but you don't need them all in production. Check out the link I provided above and search for the text "Hibernate" to get an idea of how it should work.

Comment: Not exactly, having it as "optional" takes all of the deps to the resulting WAR file, which is not necessary for the production build.